# Border-radius is not working on right side image

Tags: html, css, image, css-selectors, border-radius

I have started with a website, which uses border-radius in css. But not working as per requirement. It is getting curved on top-left and bottom-left but not on top-right and bottom-right. I have also tried specific border-top-right-radius: but still is not working.

[image]

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

/*** HEADER ***/
#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150') no-repeat;
  border-radius: 60px;
  width: 150 px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 5px;
  border-collapse: inherit;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="index.html" class="">
            <div id="logo-img" alt="Logo image"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: typo in your CSS for #logo-img, there's a space between 150 and px

Answer (score 1):

The width should have no spaces between the value and the units, otherwise it is width 100% which is the default one for a block element as `div` is.

Even though you only distinguish the part with the background at first sight but if you use your browser's inspector tools you can check it.

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

/*** HEADER ***/
#header-nav {
  background-color: #f6b319;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#logo-img {
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150') no-repeat;
  border-radius: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 5px;
  border-collapse: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Big Bite</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="index.html" class="">
            <div id="logo-img" alt="Logo image"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```